# Is there a 'IsInDesignMode' property in WinRT?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to port my application from Phone 7 and can't find the way to detect when control is in Design mode.

Got it - `Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled`

Comment: You should take that "Got it" line and put it in the answer form below instead, and mark it accepted once the site allows it, to make your question technically answered.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am using this:

```
   if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == DeviceType.Emulator)
```

and this

```
_isInDesignMode 
    = Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled
```

to check the current developing situation