# Metro / WinRt Determine if in Editor / Design Time

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In Wpf you would do something like

```
System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode()
```

But I have no idea how to check If I am in the designer in Win Rt.

Comment: Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a 'IsInDesignMode' property in WinRT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624351/is-there-a-isindesignmode-property-in-winrt)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [`Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.designmode.designmodeenabled)